# No Android SDK, neither Java found

Tags: installation, java, android

I have Java installed correctly, I did it by the manual http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

I also installed Android SDK. However when I try to create a new Project IntelliJ Idea 12 and specify Project SDk choosing New -> `/home/alex/android-sdk-linux` , it says me

```
No Java SDK of appropriate version found. In addition to the Android SDK, you need to define a JSDK 1.5, 1.6 or 1.7
```

What did I miss?

Comment: try using the ppa http://askubuntu.com/a/61873/20245

Comment: as I said, Java is installed properly. Thus, I don't need to use ppa.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Before create android select "Java module"
2. In field "Project SDK" select folder with your JDK (e.g /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle)
3. Click "Next" then "Previous"
4. Select "Android module" and shoose your folder with Android SDK

After that all my ASDK was found correctly.